# Win32 Status Bar Icon Partial Transparency Lost When SB_SETTEXT Message Sent

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

After creating an icon handle and sending the `SB_SETICON` message to a win32 Status Bar, the partially transparent pixels from the icon's alpha channel display properly.

Following this, as the title says, an `SB_SETTEXT` message sent to the same status bar part causes the partially transparent icon pixels to go opaque.

The partial transparency is restored when the main window is resized (which resize handling is another headache with this control).

Am I missing something here? Do I have to reset the icon every time I change the text?

Comment: Force a redraw? Are visual styles enabled (v6)?

Comment: I cannot reproduce it with a painted icon(RGBA:255,0,0,74), two parts status bar. Could you please show a minimal, reproducible sample without private information?

Answer (score 0):

As Anders alluded to in the question comments, common-controls v6 needs to be specified. This enables visual styles, which also changes the appearance of the status bar. I used the typical compiler directive as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview#using-manifests-or-directives-to-ensure-that-visual-styles-can-be-applied-to-applications).

```
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```